# jqgrid currency formatter returns NaN

Tags: jqgrid-formatter

I want to format the amount using the jqGrid.
When i use the below code,the column displays 'NaN' instead of currency value.

I want to display $1,000.00 or $10,000.00 in this format using jqGird

How can i achieve this ?

```
{
              name: 'amount',
              index: 'amount',
              align: 'left',
              formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$ "}
        },
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
formatter:'currency',
formatoptions: {prefix:'($', suffix:')',thousandsSeparator:',',decimalPlaces: 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i still get NaN

Comment: @user3374255..it should work for you, as you can see we are mentioning ',' asthousands seprator.

Comment: yes it worked. the returned value from query was wrong

Comment: In my case, the definition of *data* being received in *jsonReader* from server was changed, which caused the problem.